# Is it possible to test an RPC?

Tags: rpc, error

I'm doing some Web3 stuff, when an error appeared at the beginning of the process.  Targeting the problem, I realized that the problem was with my RPC (which may have crashed). I temporarily tried an RPC from Solana's doc, (Serum) and same, same problem. I then switched to the mainnet-beta RPC and there it worked. I specify that I did not exceed the rate-limit. So I wondered if there was a way to test an RPC, in case of error go to a backup?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the current health of a node using the `getHealth` RPC method defined in the [documentation](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gethealth).

For example a request would look like:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getHealth"}
'
```

Healthy Response:

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": "ok", "id": 1 }
```

Unhealthy Response:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "code": -32005,
    "message": "Node is unhealthy",
    "data": {}
  },
  "id": 1
}
```